# Application.Transpose array sets NA to range cells after printing some values correctly

Tags: excel, vba, na

I have a one dimensional string array, its size is dynamic.

After `Application.Transpose` it sets #N/A to range values.

```vb
    Dim a_ComboLovs() As String
    Dim a_metasheet As Worksheet ' consider this as worksheet object
    Dim g_ComboSourceColCount as long
    
    ' For example, setting it to some values for illustration:
    a_ComboLovs = Split("Value1,Value2,Value3,...,Value80000", ",")
    g_ComboSourceColCount = 25
    
    a_metasheet.Range(g_ComboSourceColCount & "100:" & g_ComboSourceColCount & UBound(a_ComboLovs) + 100).Value = Application.Transpose(a_ComboLovs)
    
     a_metasheet.Range(g_ComboSourceColCount & "100:" & g_ComboSourceColCount & UBound(a_ComboLovs) + 100).Name = "Evalranage"
```

The code is called in a `WorkSheet_Open` event.

Up to certain values (15k) it prints values after that it #N/A in every cell to the last.

I am trying to avoid looping.

Comment: Your code does not produce an example that can be used for debugging. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that can be used for debugging. Provide the sample data **as text that can be copy/pasted**, not a screenshot, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables).

Answer (score 1):

your `Range()` parameters were wrong

for instance `g_ComboSourceColCount & "100:"` resolves to "25100:", which is not a valid reference as a range bound

use `Cells()` instead of `Range()`, so that you can use your numeric values as row and column indexes

```
Dim a_metasheet As Worksheet ' consider this as worksheet object
    Set a_metasheet = ActiveSheet ' change it as per your needs


' For example, setting it to some values for illustration:
Dim a_ComboLovs() As String
    a_ComboLovs = Split("Value1,Value2,Value3,...,Value80000", ",")

Dim g_ComboSourceColCount As Long
    g_ComboSourceColCount = 25

    a_metasheet.Cells(100, g_ComboSourceColCount).Resize(UBound(a_ComboLovs)).Value = Application.Transpose(a_ComboLovs)
```